# Show items without record in jointable

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm building an application with CakePHP on which you can fill in surveys. The problem i came up with is the following:

I have two tables:

Surveys / SurveysUsers (HABTM)

When somebody fills in a survey a record will be made in SurveysUsers and when the Survey is accepted the survey shouldn't be visible anymore. So i want to select the surveys from the surveys table which don't have a record in the SurveysUsers table.

Hope u all can help me!

Thanks

Dwayne

Answer (score 0):

Just off the cuff, try this:

```
$this->Survey->bindModel(array('hasOne'=>array('SurveysUsers')));
$surveys = $this->Survey->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array('SurveysUsers.survey_id NOT'=>'Survey.id');
));
```

The principle is that you bind the habtm model as hasone and then you can use the fields in your conditions. Have a look in the [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM-1044)